# Windows security updates; failed status; What can be done?

Tags: windows, updates

In light of the recent WannaCry scare I was motivated to verify my Windows updates etc. & one thing I noticed in the Update History (via Control Panel) was a bunch of updates showing a "Failed" status.

Is there a way to manually reinstall these failed updates? Right clicking etc. on those "Failed" lines didn't seem to yield anything useful.
[image]

Comment: Whats your windows's version ?...

Comment: Well since they’re all Windows Defender updates you can just open Windows Defender and see what it has to say.

Comment: @DanielB Ah! Thanks. I somehow never noticed that they are all the same failed update. So, I'm using Avast as my primary Antivirus. Is it OK to use Win Defender simultaneously? Or should I be just disabling it. It does seem disabled right now.

Comment: They’re not the same. Note the different version in the parentheses. Windows Defender should get disabled as soon as you install a different AV solution. I don’t know whether it should still receive updates though.

Comment: @curious_cat Try to follow theses steps : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/windows-update-error-80070005-kb2267602/6cf718ae-c1ff-49fb-87c6-5ac46f140ff2

Comment: @DanielB Right. It was indeed disabled automatically. I'm just confused whether I ought to have both Avast and Windows Defender running both or only one. Some sources on the net claim Avast is an AV whereas Defender is anti spyware so both are allowed to run together.